# General Cypher performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

After taking part in a very interesting tutorial with a focus on Cypher, I was pleasantly surprised by the declarativeness of the Cypher query language. It's a very natural way of retrieving data from Neo4J in my opinion.

Before that, I had only used the native API. And while that is less declarative, you sort of get used to it after a while. The complex constructions are all very similar and vary only in the details for my specific project.

Still, Cypher looked more natural to me and so I am contemplating on building the second version of my application with mainly Cypher queries to interact with my database. But I encountered an issue.

There are numerous ways to convert my application into Cypher and after having tried several possible queries, all with the desired result, it appears even the fastest query is still about 20 times slower than the native API.

Now, I don't mind giving up some performance for declarativeness, but times 20 is a little bit to much for me in an application that's already struggling with performance. Is there a workaround for this issue, or do I just have to stick with the native API?

Comment: Could you share some of your queries? And perhaps your dataset? Would love to look at it, it shouldn't be that slow. Which Neo4j version are you using?

Comment: The dataset varies as it depends on the files that are uploaded by the user. I'm using 1.9.M05 atm, but I've also tried with the latest stable release. I'll post some of my queries tonight, but the issue is that I cannot be specific enough in Cypher. With the Core API I can carefully control every step, and with the knowledge of my database structure, that means I don't have to walk over tons of useless relationships, which I do have to in Cypher.

Answer (score 2):

Your conclusion sounds very familiar to me. I've also had performance issues when I used Neo4j and Spring Data Neo4j together. In the parts where performance really mattered, I switched to the core Traversal API which right now is significantly faster than an average Cypher query. This has a lot to do with the fact that there's no processing of a query and the fact that you control every aspect of the traversal. Cypher can only guess what the most optimal strategy is. I'm convinced that it will gain speed in the (near) future, but if performance really matters, I'd say stick with the core API.

Also, If you would be using java and spring data neo4j, consider using the advanced mapping mode (AspectJ) which is a lot faster than the simple mapping mode.

Comment: Actually the added layer of Spring Data also slowed down my application, based on some tests I did. So I made my own interface to directly talk with the database in the most efficient way for my specific application. I wanted to convert the implementation of that interface to Cypher, little did I know it would destroy my performance.

Comment: Although Cypher is probably always slower than using the core API, you could try to tweak your Cypher statements. This is a great resource that helped me a lot: http://thought-bytes.blogspot.in/2013/01/optimizing-neo4j-cypher-queries.html

Comment: This is another great read: http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/get-the-full-neo4j-power-by-using-the-core-java-api-for-traversing-your-graph-data-base-instead-of-cypher-query-language/. It compares the speed of the core API, the traversal API and multiple Cypher versions.

Comment: Yes, I found that link to. But my queries are far less complex than those of mr pickhardt. Never the less, after endlessly optimizing my queries, they are still not anywhere near the speed of the native api. I can only imagine the difference when you are using more complex queries.

Comment: Maybe Gemlin of the blueprints project can be an option as well, but as far as I know, it's not that widely used in combination with Neo4j.